# Making HTTP requests and sending a body of data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, client-server

I'm currently going through Guillermo Rauchs "Smashing Node.Js" Book. I'm stuck in chapter 7 where the task is to set up a client/server and to send a string from the client to the server over a http connection. The string should be printed from the server.

the client code:

```
var http = require('http'), qs = require('querystring');

function send (theName) {
    http.request({
        host: '127.0.0.1'
        , port: 3000
        , url: '/'
        , method: 'GET'
    }, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log('\n   \033[090m request complete!\033[39m');
            process.stdout.write('\n   your name:  ');
        })
    }).end(qs.stringify({ name: theName}));
}

process.stdout.write('\n  your name:  ');
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
process.stdin.on('data', function (name) {
   send(name.replace('\n', ''));
});
```

the server:

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('Done');
        console.log('\n got name \033[90m' + qs.parse(body).name + '\033[39m\n');
    });

}).listen(3000);
```

I start the client and the server. The client seems to work:

```
mles@se31:~/nodejs/tweet-client$ node client.js 

your name:  mles

   request complete!

your name:
```

However on the server side, it's only showing an undefined:

```
mles@se31:~/nodejs/tweet-client$ node server.js 

got name undefined
```

According to the book, here should be an "mles" too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
, method: 'GET'
```

should be

```
, method: 'POST'
```

GET requests do not have a body so there is nothing to parse on the server's side.

Comment: The spec is kind of vague here, but I think you're right in that node does not allow a body with a GET.

Comment: @Joe True enough. I don't know if it's the client that doesn't send data with GET, or the server that ignores data for GET, but using POST definitely fixes it.

Comment: Yep.  No on('data') events even fire in that case.